# Web jobs with Timer trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a web job that listens to two different queues and instead of writing in the Functions.cs my code (the one I inherited) looks like this.

```
 UnityContainer container = RegisterContainers();      
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration
        {
            JobActivator = new UnityResolver(container)
        };           
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        ScheduledQueueListener schedulerQueueListener = container.Resolve<ScheduledQueueListener>();
        Thread schedulerQueueThread = new Thread(schedulerQueueListener.Listen);
        schedulerQueueThread.Start();
        Thread genericQueueThread = new Thread(schedulerQueueListener.GenericQueueListen);
        genericQueueThread.Start();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

Now coming to my problem. I was hoping to create a timertrigger in Function.cs as mentioned here [Timer Trigger](https://codingcanvas.com/using-timer-triggers-with-azure-web-jobs/) which comes under nuget of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions and it breaks the current code as after the Nuget installation JoHostConfiguration is no longer valid.Is there anything that I can do in the webjob rather than adding a azure scheduler / az function to push a message to already listening queues

Answer (score 1):

The Azure WebJob libraries changed significantly from 1.x/2.x to 3.x. I'm guessing when you installed the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions Nuget package - you chose the latest version, which would upgrade your other WebJob packages to 3.x as well. In 3.x, JobHostConfiguration has been replaced.

If you revert back to your working code and then install the latest 2.x version of the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions Nuget package, you should be able to use the TimerTrigger attribute without breaking your JobHostConfiguration code.

More info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#webjobs-host

Comment: I will check this and revert back. I had this doubt when I faced the issue first so I chose not to install the latest version, but may be I could have made a mistake. Thank you :)